# 'skewY' transform isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

skewY isn't working as expected on React Native, it seems that instead of skew transform - 2D rotation is applied.

My render method:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.background}>
    <Image style={styles.bgImage}
           source={require('../assets/live_betting.png')} />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.placeholder} />
  <View style={styles.overlay}
      onClick={this.navigateToGame()}>
  </View>
</View>
```

Style sheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  background : {
    position: 'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    right:0,
    bottom:0
  },
  bgImage: {
    alignSelf : 'center'
  },
  placeholder : {
    flex: .75
  },
  overlay : {
    flex: .25,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(249,168,37,0.7)',
    transform: [{skewY: '10deg'}]
  }
});
```

This is the result:

[image]

Am I missing something?

### EDIT

It seems that all react native transforms are 3D transformations, but there isn't SkewZ transform which in this case would be proper.